# Reinstall Onedrive desktop app after uninstall on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

My OneDrive was giving me a hard time, so I wanted to reinstall it. I uninstalled it from my system, went to the Microsoft website to download again and reinstall... Some genius at Microsoft thought it would be a good idea to check my OS on and if it was windows 10, congratulate me on the fact that I already have OneDrive installed out of the box... and provide me with no way to actually download the installer again.. Great.

[image: NOT great news, Microsoft!]

The "Start OneDrive" button doesn't do anything because OneDrive is no longer installed

So does anyone know how I can download the OneDrive Desktop app (the one that lives in the system tray and creates a sync folder, not the one from the Windows store) again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OneDriveSetup.exe` is located under `Windows\SysWOW64`, per [Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/uninstall-reinstall-onedrive-windows-10/).

Comment: I had already reinstalled it when you answered, so can't verify if it was still there when it was uninstalled, but the article is helpful though! I'll mark yours as the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could check this link. I think it may accomplish what you want:

http://www.technorms.com/46217/disable-uninstall-or-reinstall-onedrive-in-windows-10

Specifically it says to navigate to: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\Update\OneDriveSetup.exe`

And then follow the install process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, but the Update folder was no longer there, so no setup file either...

Answer (score 0):

I found an installer on [CNet's Download.com](http://download.cnet.com/OneDrive-for-Windows/3000-18500_4-75820158.html) that allowed me to install OneDrive again. It was an older version but after installation it updated itself so not an issue.

Still can't quite believe there isn't an official *"Download anyway"* button on the official Microsoft site.. Ah well..